# Mocking of private member data

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm looking for the best practice for C++ codings style that will ensure ease of unit tests. The question comes from trying to implement a mock class for a private data member. The private data member is accessed in a few different methods in the class. So far all the examples I can find show how to write a mock class but not how to best write the code that will use both real and mocked objects.

In the example below I'm not sure how to get mCustom from type MyOtherClass to my mock MockMyOtherClass. I suspect my approach is wrong and thus the question.

```
class MyClass {
    MyOtherClass mCustom;
};
```

[EDIT] 
I went with a compiler directive and a added a new constructor.

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
 #include "mock.h"
#else
  #include "myotherclass.h"
#endif

class MyClass {
        MyOtherClass mCustom;
     public:
        MyClass(MyOtherClass pClass) : mCustom(pClass) {}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different strategiers you can use (and mix as needed).

1. If MyOtherClass provides fairly basic functionality and is well-tested itself, then I usually don't bother with mocking it. I just make sure that, when running unit-tests on the entire project, MyOtherClass is tested before MyClass.

   ```
   class MyClass {
   private:
       MyOtherClass mCustom;
   public:
       //...
   };
   ```
2. You can templatize MyClass, providing MyOtherClass in the real code, and a mock version of MyOtherClass in the test code.

   ```
   template <class T>
   class MyClass_impl {
   private:
       T mCustom;
   public:
       //...
   };

   typedef MyClass_impl<MyOtherClass> MyClass; // convenience typedef
   ```
3. You can split MyOtherClass in a interface class and and an implementation class. MyClass only stores a pointer to the interface class and gets a reference to an implementation when it gets instantiated.

   ```
   class MyClass {
   public:
       MyClass(MyOtherClass* aCustom) : mCustom(aCustom) {}
   private:
       MyOtherClass* mCustom;
   public:
       //...
   };
   ```
4. You can play tricks with the search-path for headers. To do this, you create a mock version of MyOtherClass in a separate directory. You then ensure that for the unit-tests, this separate directory is searched first for header files. This makes that the mock version of MyOtherClass is found first and overrides the real version of MyOtherClass.

Comment: These are all workable solutions. If, however, you go with number 4, you will be burned at the stake by any fellow developers - which is probably why it's last on this list :) Personally, I am a fan of approach 1 as the least intrusive.

Comment: In my case "MyOtherClass" talks to a device driver so I need to get that out of the loop for testing. So option 1 isn't an option. The others look interesting.

Comment: @Matt: Option 4 has actually been used by me and fellow developers in a commercial project. No burning at the stake, just using pragmatic solutions.

Comment: @Jim: Option 2 indeed does not allow for effective separation of interface and implementation of a class.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau well, it's true: it _can_ be done. It's also error-prone in a way that can cost people tons of time: the class is swapped out without there being _anything_ in the code that hints at it, and you have to think to look very closely at one line in the build process to look for a different _order_ of directories - far away from the source, where you would ordinarily look as a developer. Very dangerous. But it _can_ be done.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this problem before, I split `MyClass` into two classes: (1) a generic class with no reference to `MyOtherClass`, and (2) an implementation class that instantiated the template parameter with `MyOtherClass`. The visibility of definitions isn't identical, but I didn't find that it mattered for any practical purpose.

Then for testing, I wrote something like `MyTestOtherClass` and instantiated `MyClass` accordingly. Any number of mocking techniques can be applied to `MyTestOtherClass`, and might generate multiple class for distinct testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky approach that doesn't require any code rearchitecturing, assuming `#ifndef` header guards are being used, is to take advantage of them, by defining the header guard macros in your test code before the actual header is included.

Example:

MyClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_HPP
#define MY_CLASS_HPP

#include "MyOtherClass.hpp"

class MyClass { MyOtherClass custom; };

#endif
```

MyOtherClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef MY_OTHER_CLASS_HPP
#define MY_OTHER_CLASS_HPP

class MyOtherClass {};

#endif
```

TestCode.cpp:

```
class MyOtherClass {
    // mocking
};


#define MY_OTHER_CLASS_HPP 
// prevents the #include "MyOtherClass.hpp" in "MyClass.hpp" from doing anything
// while the mock version is used

#include "MyClass.hpp"

// test code
```

If the code you're trying to test is in a .cpp file, you can also just `#include` the .cpp file in your test (and make sure not to compile it separately to avoid duplicate definitions), to let you inject the header guard macro definitions.